# Alternative to setInterval that can be altered live

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, settimeout, setinterval

I'm working on a snake game for an assignment, where the snake has to increase it's speed when it "eats".

I used setInterval to draw the snake, but now that I have to gradually increase the speed I'm kinda lost. I have tried setTimeout also but I don't think I understand how to use it correctly.

```
//when the snake "eats"

if (snakeX == food.x && snakeY == food.y){
    food = {
        x : Math.round(Math.random()*(cvsWidth/snakeWidth-1)),
        y : Math.round(Math.random()*(cvsHeight/snakeHeight-1))
    };
    score++;
} else {
    //Remove last
    snake.pop();
}
//speed
var speed = 100;
setInterval(draw,speed);
```

Comment: `setInterval` returns a handle, your can call `clearInterval` on this, and just set up another `setInterval` with new speed.

Comment: @Keith Avoid answering questions in comments. You should expand that into a proper answer.

Comment: @forthe it's common to provide a specific answer while searching for a duplicate, and it harms nothing.

Comment: @forthe  Yeah it was late for me 00:12am,  I was ready for bed.  So thought it would be no harm pointing the OP in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assigning `setInterval` to a variable allows you to use `clearInterval` to clear it and use a new speed:

```
var interval = setInterval(draw, speed);
```

In your `snake`:

```
score++;
speed++; //Or wherever you add to speed
clearInterval(interval);
interval = setInterval(draw, speed);
```

Comment: Thank you, works great! I guess it was kinda obvious, but I'm very much new at this, so appreciate it!:)

Comment: No problem whatsoever @Meepy, ini my answer fixed your problem please accept it by clicking the grey tick mark to the left of my answer.